# What is the product of the average x and the average (1/x), where x is normally distributed.

Tags: sequences-and-series, normal-distribution

Has anyone ever seen a solution for the following...?
$$
 \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \right) \times \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right)
$$
where the x values are from a normal distribution with average $ \overline{x} $ and standard deviation $ \sigma_{\overline{x}}$ and n is fairly large (in the millions). I know the answer depends on the ratio $  \frac{\sigma_{\overline{x}}}{\overline{x}}$.

Thanks.